# Output voltage at load resistor given figure

Tags: zener

[image]

i tried to solve question this way. that 
35-20-10= 5 volt will appear at 900 resistor. but i am wrong.Correct answer is 9.47 V. can you correct me ??

Comment: You don't appear to have learned anything from the answers to [your previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/301580/output-voltage-at-transistor-of-given-figure). Start again with the basics of how Zener diodes work.

Comment: No. You are just posting your homework on here, one question at a time. Yet again, you have copied the answer from someone else and want us to show the working. Voting to close.

Comment: There are two unknown nodes in the circuit. Solve for the voltages on each of these, ignoring the zeners. Compare the voltages with the zener voltages, modify the circuit appropriately, and solve for the remaining unknowns. Repeat until you have the answer. In this case it's so obvious that you don't have to do the math particularly accurately.

Comment: I can confirm the correct answer is 9.47. Hint: potential divider

Comment: yes i know Vout = (900/2400)* vin. but i don't know how to calculate vin??

Comment: You can calculate Vin by using Andy aka's answer below. Follow that and you should be able to come up with your answer. It does come to 9.47V

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a homework question with no attempt at a solution.

Comment: i don't think so. i tried it. yes i can't understand it. so i asked hints. uint128_t.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What voltages do you get at all the nodes if you removed the zener diodes?

Write them down on each node.

If the voltage on a node where a zener would normally fit is greater than the zener voltage then replace that voltage with the zener voltage.

Re calculate the node voltages with this modified voltage.

Comment: If node 1 is at the top of the 20V zener then no, the voltage is not 7.29 volts - it's 1900/2400 *35.

Comment: ok sorry. so at node 1 i will get 27.70 volt and node 2 (1400/2400)*35=20.41

Comment: so i replace 27.70 with 20 v and 20.41 with 10 v

Comment: No, not exactly. Extra hint: If you have 20V on node 1, then how can you use 35V in your node 2 equation?

Comment: once again sorry. i am making silly mistake.so at node 2 (1400/2400)*20= 11. so i should replace it with 10 V

Comment: Almost there... Once again, node 2 is 20V, that is now your 'Vin' for your next equation, so why are you still counting the 500 ohm resistor? Slow down, look at it properly and logically and you should see it soon. Once you do see where you have gone wrong, write it down and memorise it so you can use this knowledge going forward

Comment: Also, why was this answer downvoted? Upvoted as it has given all the necessary information in order to solve this.

Comment: I was wondering that too.

Comment: yes i am getting 9.47

Comment: There you go. Now you need to make sure you keep this information. Looking back, do you know exactly where you went wrong and why? These are things you need to know before moving forward. I am not trying to be rude, I am trying to help. You need to be able to see where you went wrong and why. That is how you learn and how you are able to not make the same mistakes later

Comment: yes i will take care about it